# Fit regression line to exponential function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning, linear-regression

I am trying to learn how to interpret a linear regression model for an exponential function created with Python.  I create a model by first transforming the exponential Y data into a straight line by taking the natural log.  I then create a linear model and note the slope and intercept.  Lastly, I try to compute a sample value using the slope and intercept.  Specifically, I try to compute the Y when X = 1.1.  Y should be ~2.14 but my model interpretation produces a Y value of 3.78.

Question 1: What am I doing wrong in interpreting the model.

Question 2: I have to reshape the X array or I get an error in regr.fit.  Why do I have to reshape the X array.

The code follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model

# create some exponential data
X = np.arange(1, 10, 0.1)
print(X)
Y = np.power(2, X)
print(Y)

# transform the exponential Y data to make it a straight line
ln_Y = np.log(Y)

# show the exponential plot
plt.scatter(X, Y)
plt.show()

# Create linear regression object
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()

# reshape the X to avoid regr.fit errors
X = np.reshape(X, (X.size, 1))

# Train the model using the training sets
regr.fit(X,ln_Y)

# The coefficients
print('Slope: \n', regr.coef_)
print('Intercept: \n', regr.intercept_)

# predict Y when X = 1.1 (should be approximately 2.14354693)
# equation = e^(0.00632309*1.1) + 2.7772517886
print("predicted val = ", np.exp(0.00632309*1.1) + 2.7772517886)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you've got the latest version of scikit; I got different coeffiecients to you:

```
Slope:
 [ 0.69314718]
Intercept:
 4.4408920985e-16
```

And you'll need to take the `exp` of the whole expression, not just the x term:

```
In [17]: np.exp(0.69314718*1.1 + 4.4408920985e-16)
Out[17]: 2.1435469237522917
```

Comment: Thank you very much maxymoo.  I updated my scikit and got the same coefficients as you. Thanks for the tip and concrete example on how to interpret the model by taking the exp of the entire expression.  You are a scholar and a gentleman!